# C++ constant reference to object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

Suppose I have code:

```
void a(int& const b)
{
}
```

This snippet compiles no problem on Visual Studio 2012, however, using G++ from ideone, the program will output following compilation error:

```
error: ‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘int&’
  void a(int& const b)
                    ^
```

So I wonder which compiler is correct in this one? Is this another of the infinity + 1 bugs in Visual Studio?

Just for note, the const has no effect on visual, and you can modify `b` from within `a`

Comment: I have no idea what VS does with this, but you can't have a const reference. You can have a reference to a const `T`.

Comment: _infinity + 1 bugs_ :D

Comment: References are already 'const'.

Comment: I know you can't "re-point" references, and that you can take `const int&`, or `int const&`, but you know, there is option in visual, so I ask before writing non-compilant code

Comment: The qualifier makes no sense... why would it let you write that... the qualifier would be applying to the underlying "pointer" that is the reference, but that's already inherently unmodifiable by the nature of references. g++ is almost certainly correct.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ grammar looks the following way for declarators

```
ptr-operator:
* attribute-specifier-seqopt cv-qualifier-seqopt
& attribute-specifier-seqopt
&& attribute-specifier-seqopt
```

As it is seen references have no cv-qualifier-seq.

So I think that it is either a MS VC++ bug or a language extension.:)

Comment: quite useless language extension tbh :D